# attach camera to moving object/entity

Tags: aframe

I'm trying to attach my camera to a moving ride vehicle. i want to make a ghost train where the look controls are enabled. my problem is when i attach the camera to the ride cart it the moves the cart the direction the user looks. i want to just have it as if the user is sat in the ride and they can look around. so when the cart moves forward the camera stays in the same position on the cart and moves with it. hope that makes sense. Heres the main part of the code i have so far.
im a student learning so i know my code probably isnt best practice.

```
<a-entity id="rigCart" rotation="0 91 0">
    <a-entity gltf-model="#cart" scale="0.1 0.1 0.1" rotation="0 125 0" position="0 .5 7.5" animation="property: position; dur:9000; from:0 0.5 7.5;to:0 0.5 -27.5"></a-entity>
    <a-camera wasd-controls-enabled="false" position="0 1.5 6.5">
       <a-entity
            cursor="fuse: true; fuse-timeout: 500"
            position="0 0 -1.5"
            geometry="primitive: ring; radiusInner: 0.01; radiusOuter: 0.02"
            material="color: #FFFFFF; shader: flat">
       </a-entity>
   </a-camera>
</a-entity>
```

i tried putting the cart into the camera entity but it just moves the cart off track in the direction the user looks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to move your rig to change the position of all child objects, being both the model and the camera.

Right now you just animate the model off into the distance. It doesn't affect the camera - it's just a separate entity sharing the same parent.

```html
<script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.5.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
<a-scene>
  <a-box position="-1 0.5 -3" rotation="0 45 0" color="#4CC3D9"></a-box>
  <a-sphere position="0 1.25 -5" radius="1.25" color="#EF2D5E"></a-sphere>
  <a-cylinder position="1 0.75 -3" radius="0.5" height="1.5" color="#FFC65D"></a-cylinder>
  <a-plane position="0 0 -4" rotation="-90 0 0" width="4" height="4" color="#7BC8A4"></a-plane>
  <a-entity position="0 0.6 0" 
            animation="property: position; dur:9000; from:0 0.5 7.5;to:0 0.5 -5.5">
    <a-box color="blue" scale="0.5 0.5 2"></a-box>
    <a-entity camera look-controls position="0 1 0"></a-entity>
  </a-entity>
  <a-sky color="#ECECEC"></a-sky>
</a-scene>
```